# react-native passing data to - (UIView *)view from javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uitextview, react-native

I have my `- (UIView *)view` method which returns a `uitextview`

it looks like this

```
- (UIView *)view
{
  UITextView *tx =[[UITextView alloc]init];
  [tx setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
  [tx setTag:1];
  tx.delegate = self;

  return tx;
}
```

I want to be able to pass javascript values to this method while I am creating the `UITextView`. I am not sure if react-native supports that.
Simple example, I want it to look like this.

```
- (UIView *)view
{
  UITextView *tx =[[UITextView alloc]init];
  [tx setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
  [tx setTag:1];
  tx.delegate = self;

  //here is where I use the passed in values
  tx.text=javascriptValuePassedIn;
  return tx;
}
```

I need to load some data into the `UITextView` on creation which I want to pass in from javascript. I cannot use delegates at the point of creation. The only way I can think of on how to do this would be to set up some restful services to grab the data and work with it on `UITextView` creation.

Answer (score 0):

Data from the top down is a limitation with react-native. I don't think you can push data from JS to Native ios code on component creation. I had to set up some restful services to grab the data when the component was being created.